# How to make Moving road/track for android game?

Tags: opengl, android, movement, cocos2d, html-canvas

I am very much new to Android game development. and i have little idea about the canvas and open GL. in one of my requirement i wanted to draw a moving road/track(Jazzy). how should i start. please suggest me some approach/tutorial. Thanks

Below is the link for the reference..please take look at the road only

http://www.miniclip.com/games/zoo-racer/en/

Comment: A 'moving road/track(Jazzy)'? I have no idea what you're talking about... Can you at least add a screenshot of something similar?

Comment: http://www.miniclip.com/games/zoo-racer/en/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much to say about it, just look into basic 2D game tutorials and they should give you enough information. I've never worked with Android so I don't have any links at hand, but you need the following:

1. Draw the track; for simplicity your track can be one complete image and you simply draw it on the background.
2. A [2D camera](http://www.david-gouveia.com/2d-camera-with-parallax-scrolling-in-xna/) that changes your point of view of the scene. Basically it creates a View Matrix for you to pass OpenGL when drawing.
3. A player/car object with X,Y position in the track. Draw the player on top of the track at that position.
4. Fix the 2D camera to your player (e.g. `camera.Position = player.Position;`).